# How to move an index of a clicked item to another component that is not a parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Expecting effect: click `<li>` --> take index --> send this index to component `Watch`.
When I click `<li>`, I grab the index and move it to the`Watch` component. However, when I click the second `li` it returns the index of the one I clicked for the first time. I think this is because it updates this index via `componentDidMount`. How can I reference this index after `componentDidMount`?

**Todo**

```
class Todo extends Component {
      render () {
        return (
          <div className = "itemTodos" onClick={()=> this.props.selectTodo(this.props.index)}>
          </div>
        )
      } 
    }

    export default Todo;
```

**App**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state {
      selectedTodoIndex: index
    }

  }

  selectTodo = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedTodoIndex: index
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
           <ul>
      {
        this.state.todos
          .map((todo, index) =>
            <Todo
              key={index}
              index={index}
              todo={todo}
              selectTodo ={this.selectTodo}
            />
          )
      }
    </ul>
          <Watch
            selectedTodoIndex = {selectedTodoIndex}
          />
      </div>
    )
  } 
}

export default App;
```

**Watch**

```
class Watch extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectIndex: null
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      selectIndex:  this.props.selectedTodo
    });
 }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Comment: Where do you render `Todo`? Also in `Watch`, you pass the prop `selectedTodoIndex` but never receives `selectedTodo`

Comment: @Vencovsky todo render in app

Comment: Please add the correct code to your answer

Comment: You shouldn't revolve your code around indexes provided by the array. You should add an id to each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you you use selectedTodoIndex in

```
<Watch
        selectedTodoIndex = {selectedTodoIndex}
      />
```

but it not specified in your render code. Add

```
const {selectedTodoIndex} = this.state;
```

in render function.

Second, use componentDidUpdate in Watch for update inner state on props update:

```
 class Watch extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectIndex: null
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      selectIndex:  this.props.selectedTodo
    });
 }

 componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.selectedTodo !== this.props.selectedTodo)
        this.setState({
          selectIndex:  this.props.selectedTodo
        });
 }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong your Todo component is in watch??. So **Watch** component should be like this :

```
render () {
    return (
      <div>
       <Todo index={this.state.selectedIndex} selectedTodo={this.props.selectedTodoIndex}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Here i made codesandbox of this code . Feel free to checkout and let me know if you any doubt. Code link : **https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-chaplygin-ws1zz**

Comment: Now move this index from the 'App' component to the 'Watch' component and save in state, which is not a child. When I click `li` index change in component `Watch`

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of improvements to be made. But I believe what you are looking for is **getDerivedStateFromProps** lifeCycle method in Watch Component. So the code will be:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.selectedTodoIndex !== prevState.selectedTodoIndex) {
    return { selectIndex: nextProps.selectedTodoIndex }
  }
}
```

This will check if the selected index has changed in App Component, if yes it will update the state in Watch Component.